# H2 database issue with select query - wrong results

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, h2

I have a very strange behavior on my h2 database with a simple select query on a specific DB table. This same query works fine with MySQL, however if i switch my application's underlying DB to H2 it returns wrong results (application can run both on MySQL as also on H2 DB).

I have a second almost identical query which works fine so i am posting here both for better understanding.

There are two tables: "StudyProtocolNames" and "StudyRfCoils" which have a N-1 relation with table "StudyDetails" (StudyDetails.stId primary key is foreign key on both StudyProtocolNames and StudyRfCoils).

Here is the parent table class "StudyDetails":

```
@Entity
@Table(name="StudyDetails", 
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "StudyInstanceUID"))
public class StudyDetails implements Serializable {  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="StId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long stId;

    @Column(name="StudyInstanceUID", unique=true, nullable = false)
    private String studyInstanceUID;

    @Column(name="SoapResponse")
    private int soapResponse;

    @Column(name="PatientName")
    private String patientName;

    @Column(name="RfCoil", nullable = false)
    private String rfCoil;

    @Column(name="ProtocolName", nullable = false)
    private String protocolName;

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "studyDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<StudyProtocolNames> studyProtocolNames = new HashSet<>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "studyDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<StudyRfCoils> studyRfCoils = new HashSet<>(0);
    ...
}
```

and here are "StudyProtocolNames" and "StudyRfCoils" classes:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="StudyProtocolNames")
public class StudyProtocolNames implements Serializable {

    private static long serialVersionUID = -298254562330274106L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PnId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long pnId;


    @Column(name="StudyInstanceUID")
    private String studyInstanceUID;

    @Column(name="ProtocolName", nullable = false)
    private String protocolName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "StId", referencedColumnName="StId")
    private StudyDetails studyDetails;
    ...
}
```

...

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="StudyRfCoils")
public class StudyRfCoils implements Serializable {

    private static long serialVersionUID = -298254562330274106L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "RfcId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long rfcId;

    @Column(name="StudyInstanceUID")
    private String studyInstanceUID;

    @Column(name="RfCoil", nullable = false)
    private String rfCoil;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "StId", referencedColumnName="StId")
    private StudyDetails studyDetails;
    ...
}
```

In a certain point of my application, before inserting a new record to "StudyProtocolNames", i check if there is already a record with the same studyInstanceUID and protocolName. If there is already such a record, this method returns true.

```
@Override
public Boolean checkDicomStudyProtocolNameExistForStudy(String studyInstanceUID, String protocolName) {

    Boolean status = false;

    List<String> results=new ArrayList<>();
    Session s=HibernateUtil.openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    String hql = "FROM StudyProtocolNames E WHERE E.studyInstanceUID = :studyInstanceUID AND E.protocolName = :protocolName";
    Query query = s.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("protocolName", protocolName.trim());
    query.setParameter("studyInstanceUID", studyInstanceUID);
    results = query.list();
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    log.info(results.size() + " Records found for study in checkDicomStudyProtocolNameExistForStudy: " + studyInstanceUID + " and protocolName" + protocolName);
    if(results.isEmpty()) {
        status = false;
    } else {
        status = true;
    }

    return status;
}
```

I am doing the exact same check on "StudyRfCoils" table (different columns same logic):

```
@Override
public Boolean checkDicomStudyRfCoilExistForStudy(String studyInstanceUID, String rfCoil) {

    Boolean status = false;

    List<String> results=new ArrayList<>();
    Session s=HibernateUtil.openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    String hql = "FROM StudyRfCoils E WHERE E.studyInstanceUID = :studyInstanceUID AND E.rfCoil = :rfCoil";
    Query query = s.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("rfCoil", rfCoil.trim());
    query.setParameter("studyInstanceUID", studyInstanceUID);
    results = query.list();
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    log.info(results.size() + " Records found for study in checkDicomStudyRfCoilExistForStudy: " + studyInstanceUID + " and rfCoil: " + rfCoil);
    if(results.isEmpty()) {
        status = false;
    } else {
        status = true;
    }

    return status;

}
```

The first check query for table StudyProtocolNames works fine and if a record with the same "studyInstanceUID" and "protocolName" then it returns true.

The second query however always returns FALSE. It can not locate already existing records with the same "studyInstanceUID" and "rfCoil". So i end in my DB table with multiple records with the same values for columns "studyInstanceUID" and "rfCoil":

[image]

Another strange fact is that this second check query works FINE when i switch to MySQL. This strange behavior is happening only when using H2 DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this behavior was caused by the trim() i was performing to rfCoil string value:

```
@Override
public Boolean checkDicomStudyRfCoilExistForStudy(String studyInstanceUID, String rfCoil) {
    ...
    query.setParameter("rfCoil", rfCoil.trim());
    ...
```

However in MySQL this is not happening